# Click the button and it sends that info into another box on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I want to be able to click on a button then that puts that information into another part on the page (in a box). However, I want the ability to remove this from that box too.

What is the best way to do this using html and javascript?

thanks

Comment: What have u tried? Any html, css or js code?

Comment: Please precise what you mean by: `that information`, `into another part of the page`, `remove this from that box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `html`, `css` and `jQuery` you can get your desired output.
Please check below code.

```js
function getHtml() {
  var test = $("#input").text();
  $("#output").show();
  $("#remove").show();
  $("#output").text(test);

}

function remove() {
  $("#output").hide();
  $("#remove").hide();

}
```

```css
#output {
  display: none;
}

#remove {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input">
  Input: welcome
</div>
<button onClick="getHtml()">Click</button>
<div id="output">
</div>
<button id="remove" onClick="remove()">Remove</button>
```